# Grant the Synapse Administrator role without already having the role

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have an Azure Synapse Workspace for which I have the owner role in the subscription, resource group, and Resource itself, and I am the `Microsoft Entra admin` for the Synapse Workspace, but a former employee had the Synapse Administrator role for managing the Synapse Workspaces. Despite my owner roles, when I follow the [official instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-add-admin) by opening the Synapse workspace, and selecting Manage > Access control, I get a message saying `You do not have permission to review Synapse RBAC role assignments` and attempting to add a new Synapse Administrator role assignment fails.

How can I as the resource owner get access to the former employee's work in that synapse workspace?

Comment: could you please include the screenshot of your Acccess contro(IAM)
https://i.imgur.com/jzGqgEa.png

Comment: No. (a) Not sure this helps, given that I specified that I have the Owner role, and (b) as the owner, I'm free to assign myself any other roles, so if you think I'm missing a role, I can assign it to myself as part of a solution.  The issue, as I see it though, is that the `Access Control (IAM)` panel in the azure portal does not have the ability to assign the Synapse Administrator role, which can only be done in the Workspace by those who already have the Synapse Administrator role in that workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As the Owner of the Resource Group, it is possible to grant yourself the Synapse Administrator role. You may need to do this from the Azure Portal rather than inside the Synapse Studio interface. It can be done using PowerShell or the UI, but this link has very helpful information if you are comfortable using PowerShell:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/retrieve-azure-synapse-role-based-access-control-rbac/ba-p/3466419

I swear that there used to be a specific help article for this topic for situations where the original Synapse Administrator user has left the company or is otherwise unavailable. Still, my Bing skills need to be better today.

Answer (score -1):

As per this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-review-synapse-rbac-role-assignments)

> A guest users (users from a different AD tenant) **can also see and manage role assignment after being assigned the Synapse Administrator role.**

- Make sure from the account you are trin to access the workspace is from same AD tenant.
- If you are guest user then who belong to the same Tenant (not a guest user) and who is owner of the Synapse workspace ask that user should be able to add your guest user id and grant synapse admin permission.

***To assign Synapse Administrator role to yourself you need the owner role on resource group and resource it will take time to reflect changes.***

You can also see the **MSQnA thread** [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/732285/synapse-studio-403-unauthorised-even-with-owner-pe) where @Gaurav Batta told he assigned Synapse Administrator role to himself but is should be user from the same tenant.

Comment: Notice the phrase `after being assigned the Synapse Administrator role` in your solution implies that the the Synapse Administrator has been assigned by an existing Synapse Administrator.  In my case, the only Synapse Administrator was a former employee who has left the company and who's Azure Entra ID no longer exists -- so there are no Synapse Administrators left to assign someone the Synapse Administrator role.

Comment: but it's for guest users for same tenet users the owner can review and assign Administrator role to himself.

Comment: I would happily accept that answer if you could show me detailed instructions for how do to that. I'm very familiar with assigning azure ad roles, but this role is managed within the Synapse portal, and even as the owner of the resource, I'm unable to assign myself or anyone else the Synapse Administrator role.

Comment: are you from the same tenant where resource is created then you will be able to do it if not then the person from that tenant have to assign you the role.

Comment: The Synapse workspace is in my tenant, in a subscription and resource group that I have the owner role (and therefor I can assign myself any role for that resource).  As I've repeatedly explained. The Azure Synapse privileges are not managed in the Azure portal and because the only Synapse Administrator left the company, there is no one to ask to assign me the Synapse Administrator role.